# Count number of objects by date in daterange

Tags: python, django, performance, django-orm

In a Django project, I have these simplified models defined:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=96)

class Event(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nom', max_length=96)

    date_start = models.DateField()
    date_end = models.DateField()

    participants = models.ManyToManyField(to='People', through='Participation')

class Participation(models.Model):
    """Represent the participation of 1 people to 1 event, with information about arrival date and departure date"""

    people = models.ForeignKey(to=People, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(to=Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    arrival_d = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    departure_d = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Now, I need generate a participation graph: for each single event day, I want the corresponding total number of participations.
Currently, I use this awful code:

```
def daterange(start, end, include_last_day=False):
    """Return a generator for each date between start and end"""
    days = int((end - start).days)
    if include_last_day:
        days += 1
    for n in range(days):
        yield start + timedelta(n)

class ParticipationGraph(DetailView):

    template_name = 'events/participation_graph.html'
    model = Event

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        labels = []
        data = []

        for d in daterange(self.object.date_start, self.object.date_end):
            labels.append(formats.date_format(d, 'd/m/Y'))
            total_participation = self.object.participation_set
                .filter(arrival_d__lte=d, departure_d__gte=d).count()
            data.append(total_participation)

        kwargs.update({
            'labels': labels,
            'data': data,
        })
        return super(ParticipationGraph, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Obviously, I run a new SQL query for each day between `Event.date_start` and `Event.date_end`. **Is there a way to get the same result with a reduced number of SQL query (ideally, only one)?**

I tried many aggregation tools from Django orm (values(), distinct(), etc.) but I always fall to the same issue: I don't have a field with a simple date value, I only have start and end date (in Event) and departure and arrival date (in Participation), so I can't find a way to group my results by date.

Comment: Maybe you should tag your question with `python` too. That would draw more attention. Also `django-orm` seems more appropriate than just `orm`.

Comment: Thanks, I've done what you suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that the current approach is expensive because, for each day, you are re-querying the DB for participants that you already retrieved earlier. I would instead approach this by doing a one-time query to the DB to get the participants and then use that data to populate your result data structure.

One structural change I would make to your solution is that instead of tracking two lists where each index corresponds to a day and the participation, aggregate the data in a dictionary mapping the day to the number of participants. If we aggregate results this way, we can always convert this to the two-lists at the end if needed.

Here is what my general (pseudo-codeish) approach is:

```
def formatDate(d):
    return formats.date_format(d, 'd/m/Y')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    # initialize the results with dates in question
    result = {}
    for d in daterange(self.object.date_start, self.object.date_end):
        result[formatDate(d)] = 0

    # for each participant, add 1 to each date that they are there
    for participant in self.object.participation_set:
        for d in daterange(participant.arrival_d, participant.departure_d):
            result[formatDate(d)] += 1

    # if needed, convert result to appropriate two-list format here

    kwargs.update({
        'participation_amounts': result
    })
    return super(ParticipationGraph, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

In terms of performance, both approaches do the same number of operations. In your approach, for every day, d, you filter over every participant, p. Thus, the number of operations is O(dp). In my approach, for each participant I go through every day they attended (worse cast every day, d). Thus, it is also O(dp).

The reason to prefer my approach is what you pointed out. It only hits the database once to retrieve the participant list. Thus, it is less dependent on network latency. It does sacrifice some of the perf benefits that you get from SQL queries over python code. However, the python code is not too complex and should be fairly easy to process for events that even have hundreds of thousands of people.

Comment: It's a very elegant and clever solution. I did tested it, and it does exactly what I needed. After performing a few optimizations (related to some specificity not mentioned here), your solution takes about the same time to execute but reduce a lot the number of queries (specially for long events). I was too focused on how to perform this well only with SQL, but adding a few Python logic works very well too. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I saw this question few days ago and honoured it with an upvote, since it is really well written and the problematics is very interesting. Finally I found some time to dedicate to its solution.

Django is a variation of a Model-View-Controller called Model-Template-View. My approach would follow thus the paradigm "fat model and thin controllers" (or translated to conform with Django "fat model and thin views").

Here is how I would rewrite the models:

```
import pandas

from django.db import models
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=96)


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nom', max_length=96)
    date_start = models.DateField()
    date_end = models.DateField()
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(to='Person', through='Participation')

    @cached_property
    def days(self):
        days = pandas.date_range(self.date_start, self.date_end).tolist()
        return [day.date() for day in days]

    @cached_property
    def number_of_participants_per_day(self):
        number_of_participants = []
        participations = self.participation_set.all()
        for day in self.days:
            count = len([par for par in participations if day in par.days])
            number_of_participants.append((day, count))
        return number_of_participants


class Participation(models.Model):
    people = models.ForeignKey(to=Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(to=Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    arrival_d = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    departure_d = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    @cached_property
    def days(self):
        days = pandas.date_range(self.arrival_d, self.departure_d).tolist()
        return [day.date() for day in days]
```

All calculations are placed in the models. Information that depends on the data stored in the database is made available as **[`cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional)**.

Let's see an example for `Event`:

```
djangocon = Event.objects.create(
    name='DjangoCon Europe 2018',
    date_start=date(2018,5,23),
    date_end=date(2018,5,28)
)
djangocon.days
>>> [datetime.date(2018, 5, 23),
     datetime.date(2018, 5, 24),
     datetime.date(2018, 5, 25),
     datetime.date(2018, 5, 26),
     datetime.date(2018, 5, 27),
     datetime.date(2018, 5, 28)]
```

I used `pandas` for generating the date range, which is probably an overkill for your application, but it has nice syntax and is good for demonstrational purposes. You can generate the date range in your own way.
To get this result there was only one query. The `days` is available as any other field.
The same thing I made in `Participation`, here are some examples:

```
antwane = Person.objects.create(name='Antwane')
rohan = Person.objects.create(name='Rohan Varma')
cezar = Person.objects.create(name='cezar')
```

They all want to visit DjangoCon Europe in 2018, but not all of them are attending all days:

```
p1 = Participation.objects.create(
    people=antwane,
    event=djangocon,
    arrival_d=date(2018,5,23),
    departure_d=date(2018,5,28)
)
p2 = Participation.objects.create(
    people=rohan,
    event=djangocon,
    arrival_d=date(2018,5,23),
    departure_d=date(2018,5,26)
)
p3 = Participation.objects.create(
    people=cezar,
    event=djangocon,
    arrival_d=date(2018,5,25),
    departure_d=date(2018,5,28)
)
```

Now we want to see how many participants there are for every day the event is going on. We track the number of SQL queries too.

```
from django.db import connection
djangocon = Event.objects.get(pk=1)
djangocon.number_of_participants_per_day
>>> [(datetime.date(2018, 5, 23), 2),
     (datetime.date(2018, 5, 24), 2),
     (datetime.date(2018, 5, 25), 3),
     (datetime.date(2018, 5, 26), 3),
     (datetime.date(2018, 5, 27), 2),
     (datetime.date(2018, 5, 28), 2)]

connection.queries
>>>[{'time': '0.000', 'sql': 'SELECT "participants_event"."id", "participants_event"."name", "participants_event"."date_start", "participants_event"."date_end" FROM "participants_event" WHERE "participants_event"."id" = 1'},
    {'time': '0.000', 'sql': 'SELECT "participants_participation"."id", "participants_participation"."people_id", "participants_participation"."event_id", "participants_participation"."arrival_d", "participants_participation"."departure_d" FROM "participants_participation" WHERE "participants_participation"."event_id" = 1'}]
```

There are two queries. The first one fetches the object `Event` and the second gets the number of participants per day for the event.

Now it's up to you to use it in your views as you please. And thanks to the cached properties you won't need to repeat the database query to get the result.

You can follow the same principle and maybe add property to list all participants for each day of an event. It could look like:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # ... snip ...
    @cached_property
    def participants_per_day(self):
        participants  = []
        participations = self.participation_set.all().select_related('people')
        for day in self.days:
            people = [par.people for par in participations if day in par.days]
            participants.append((day, people))
        return participants

    # refactor the number of participants per day
    @cached_property
    def number_of_participants_per_day(self):
        return [(day, len(people)) for day, people in self.participants_per_day]
```

I hope you like this solution.

Comment: Yeah, I like your solution too. I use a lot cached property in my models, and putting the list of days of the event and for each participation make sense, since it's an information I may reuse later. I implemented and checked the amount of time needed to render the page and number of queries. It's equivalent to Rohan's solution. Thanks !

Comment: @Antwane In terms of performance this solution can match Rohan's solution, but can't beat it. You can't go below 1 database hit, that limit can't be broken. However I'd strongly suggest you to put your business logic and all database operations in the model layer. Please check the edit to see an example how the solution can be expanded.